# posicionar en linea

Tags: css

Quiero posicionar en fila, pero no encima

```css
.caja {
  display: inline-block;
}

.uno {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.dos {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="caja">
  <div class="uno">
  </div>

  <div class="dos">


  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes quitar el `inline-block` del padre y puedes agregar la propiedad `float: left;` a los dos elementos para que flote uno al lado del otro.

```css
.uno {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}

.dos {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="caja">
  <div class="uno">
  </div>

  <div class="dos">


  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplemente debes darle la propiedad `display: inline-block;` a los elementos que quieres posicionar uno al lado del otro y no a su elemento padre:

**Nota:** la propiedad `vertical-align` alinea verticalmente los elementos que contienen `display: inline-block;`

```css
.uno {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.dos {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="caja">
  <div class="uno">
  </div>

  <div class="dos">


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hay un espacio entre los 2 cuadrados, como los junto mas?

Comment: @hubman ok, debes tener en cuenta que los navegadores agregan ese espacio de forma predeterminada para los elementos que tienen `display: inline-block;`, para quitarlo podrías usar un margin-left con valor negativo en el segundo elemento, te he editado la respuesta !

Comment: no existe `vertical-align:` **center**;... sería acaso `middle` pero aún así no lo necesitas...

Comment: oh que torpe fui @aldanux tienes razón confundí los valores de dos propiedades, editaré la respuesta ... no se necesitan en este ejemplo pero es bueno hacer énfasis en que existe la propiedad para que en el caso que tenga elementos de diferente altura no le genere un dolor de cabeza ubicarlos como desee

Answer (score 3):

Una solución moderna:

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}

.div {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px; 
}

.uno { 
  background-color: red;
}

.dos {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="div uno"></div>
  <div class="div dos"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Como no lo pensé antes jajaja fácil y rápido !!